# How to power a motherboard from a 24V source?

Tags: voltage-regulator, atx

I would like to power a ATX motherboard from a 12V or 24V power source.

Does anybody have some circuit?

Comment: Why not buy a 12/24v power supply? It would be hard to beat the price unless your qty was large.

Comment: What research have you done on this? Are you aware of the signalling complexity of ATX supplies?

Comment: The *simplest* solution would be to buy a 12V or 24V mains inverter and use a standard ATX PSU.

Comment: Does it need to be an ATX form factor explicitly?  There are lots of PC104 form factor options available, and 12/24VDC power supplies are common in that space.  Unless this is a for-fun project, why build when you can buy what you need?

Comment: Study the ATX supply specification, conclude that it will not be easy to implement all that. Then order a "PicoPSU" module which can be used to power an ATX motherboard from a single 12 V supply. If you insist on 24 V, get a buck converter module to convert that 24V into 12V, note that the current might be significant, you will need a beefy buck converter module.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how much power you need for your overall system, the iTuner picoPSU 120w wide input might do the trick: http://www.logicsupply.com/products/pico120wi_25

If you need more power, the M4-ATX is good for 250w, but mounting it can sometimes be a challenge: http://www.logicsupply.com/products/m4_atx

The M4 has ignition sensing intelligence, but you can set it to dumb mode with the dip switches.